# Jquery selector multiple href - dynamically get href value

Tags: jquery

I've number of html href as shown below:

```
<a id="link1" href="http://www.google.com">USA </a>    
<a id="link2" href="http://www.google.com.au">AU </a>
<a id="link2" href="http://www.google.com.nz">NZ </a>
```

I've jquery as below:

```
<script>
    $("a").click(function () {
      var link = $('a').attr('href');
      alert(link);
      dosomethingforlink(link);

    });
</script>
```

Basically, with one click function above I would like to get the href value of `<a>` tag (which is clicked) and do something different for each link.

Or do I need to create `(#id).click` function for each Ids?

Could someone please help me if the above is possible using Jquery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this  :

```
$("a").click(function () {
  var link = $(this).attr('href');
  alert(link);
  dosomethingforlink(link);
});
```

I have changed `$('a')` to `$(this)` as `$('a')` will get all of the anchors .. `$(this)` will only get the currently clicked one.

[Here is a quick working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3jVht/) .. you will see the last line is `event.preventDefault()` - it prevents the default action (ie following the href) from happening and allowing your function to execute. [`event.preventDefault()` docs here](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

Comment: Hi @ManseUK, dosomethingforlink(link) function uses the ActiveXObject. The IE shows that "might not be safe message.." dialog. When use click no the existing <a href> gets executed. Is it possible to do nothing if use clicks "No".

Answer (score 1):

Something like this may be

```
<script>
    $("a").click(function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();          
      var link = $(this).attr('href');
      alert(link);
      dosomethingforlink(link);
    });
</script>
```

Adds:

use event.preventDefault() from navigation to the url in anchor tag

Answer (score 1):

```
$("a").click(function (evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      var link = $(this).attr('href');
      alert(link);
      dosomethingforlink(link);
});
```

you should use `preventDefault()` otherwise you won't be able to execute further code (your link gets clicked and the page is immediately changed)

Answer (score 0):

ID's should be unique, so do not use the same ID on more than one element.

Something like this maybe:

```
$("a[id^='link']").on('click', function (e){
  e.preventDefault();
  switch ($(this).attr('href')) {
     case 'http://www.google.com' :
         //do something
     break;
     case 'http://www.google.com.au' :   
         //do something
     break;
     default: 
        //do something else

....etc
  }
});
```